# How to get value from html javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a popup script to show full data from MySQL,

```
<?php
$namedetails = $_GET['viewdetails'];
    include 'connection.php';
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Name='$namedetails' ");
    foreach ($result as $row);
?>
<?php /* Here all data row based on Name to show */ ?>
```

The script works properly by:

```
<a href="MyWebsite.com/listpage/?viewdetails=John">View details</a>
```

But my problem is, I cannot get the popup to update without refreshing the page. So I've tried to use:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="jwpopupLink" viewdetails="John" >View Full Details</a>
```

The popup shows up without refreshing the page, but it has no data. How can I get viewdetails/John value for $namedetails?

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Popup</title>

<style>
body{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
/* jwpopup box style */
.popheader { font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; }
.jwpopup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 180px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.jwpopup-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 900px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

.jwpopup-head {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    color: white;
    background: #006faa; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#006faa, #002c44); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#006faa, #002c44); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#006faa, #002c44); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#006faa, #002c44); /* Standard syntax */
}
.jwpopup-main {padding: 5px 16px;}
.jwpopup-foot {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 3px 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #006faa; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#006faa, #002c44); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#006faa, #002c44); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#006faa, #002c44); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#006faa, #002c44); /* Standard syntax */
}

/* animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* close */
.close {
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: none;
}
.close:hover, .close:focus {
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<?php
$namedetails = $_GET['viewdetails'];
    include 'connection.php';
    $result = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Name='$namedetails' ");
    foreach ($result as $row);
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="jwpopupLink"></a> 
<!-- jwpopup box -->
<div id="jwpopupBox" class="jwpopup">
    <!-- jwpopup content -->
    <div class="jwpopup-content">
        <div class="jwpopup-head">
            <span class="close">Close</span>
            <?php echo "<span class='popheader' style='color: #ffff00;'><strong>+ ".$row['Name']."</strong></span>" ?>
        </div>
        <div class="jwpopup-main">
</br>       
<?php
     if($result->num_rows == 0) 
     {
     echo 
     "</br></br><h1 style='text-align: center;'><strong>Ups... No Data Found for <span style='color: #1512ba'>$dnview</strong></span></h1></br></br></br>";
     } 
     else 
    {
    echo "

<table style='width: 100%; font-weight: bold;' border='2'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan='2' style='font-weight: bold;'><h4>Name</h4></th>
            <th style='font-weight: bold;'><h4>City</h4></th>
            <th style='font-weight: bold;'><h4>Country</h4></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style='font-size: 12px;'>
                <span style='color: #1512ba;'>".$row['Name']."</span>
            </td>
            <td style='font-size: 12px;'>
                <span style='color: #1512ba;'>".$row['City']."</span>
            </td>
            <td style='font-size: 12px;'>
                <span style='color: #1512ba;'>".$row['Country']."</span>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</br>               
    ";
    }
?>

        </div>
        <div class="jwpopup-foot">
            <span><strong>MyDomain</strong></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>


var jwpopup = document.getElementById('jwpopupBox');

var mpLink = document.getElementById("jwpopupLink");

var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

mpLink.onclick = function() {
    jwpopup.style.display = "block";
}

close.onclick = function() {
    jwpopup.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == jwpopup) {
        jwpopup.style.display = "none";
    }
}

var url = window.location.href; {
if(url.indexOf('?viewdetails=') != -1) {
    jwpopup.style.display = "block"; }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_Without refresh the page_" smells like you need Ajax to me

Comment: And how do you trigger popup opening? Please supply code example for it.

Comment: Just a heads up: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You are allowing a user to directly run SQL queries on your database simply by providing a well crafted `viewdetails` query parameter.

Comment: Was just going to say something about SQL injection, @JanneKlouman good catch. If you're doing a popup window, you will need to provide the logic that is triggering it..

Comment: `javascript:void(0)` is not a viable solution. If you are not satisfied by the default behavior of a link, replace it with a button or use `preventDefault` on the click event...

Comment: PHP is server-side, not client side. If you want to get information from a database onclick, you want to use Ajax like @AntonisTsimourtos said.

Comment: @MarcinPewiński I add the full code

Comment: @JanneKlouman Really, why? I am new on coding, so how to prevent it?

Comment: @Gian, I suggest you to analize source of the page and see if there is a data from PHP present inside '#jwpopupBox' element. This way you can checkif this is a problem with javascript, or maybe the data never came from the server so the popup really should be empty.

Comment: @MarcinPewiński Thanks for your kind reply. 
Do you means the error is not from $namedetails = $_GET['viewdetails']; ... and <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="jwpopupLink" viewdetails="John" >View Full Details</a>, but from other path? 
But when I use Url parameter like "?viewdetails=AnyName" it shows correctly, while use link clicks it shows no data. I just wonder how to get "viewdetails" input value from the link. Sorry I really newbie on coding

Comment: @Gian if you are a beginner I think you should first get some good tutorial explaining how to obtain data from PHP using ajax call. This will help you a lot.